# Capturing Effective log in and log out time in a system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, session

Here i am trying to capture the total log in and log off time of a system .
Suppose A user log in to system At 9AM then lock the system (windows+L) on 11AM then again unlock it  on 3PM and lock/log off for the day on 6 PM .then effective timing is 2+3=5 hrs.

If user lock the system then timing should not be counted ..
Aim of this application to track the effective time of any user log in and shoot a mail to the manager ...I am concentrating on the time tracking level first.

I think session is the best way to capture the scenario ..but have to keep the scenario .if on the same day user log on then lock the system then shut down completely the system ..again on the same day he starts the system and work onward then ..all the working time will be under a same day ..

Calculation needs to be done ...effective working hours for a user in a 24 day span .

Comment: So what exactly are you asking for, and what have you tried?

Comment: I think question is how to detect when computer isn't being used basically... but I think this is unfair to your staff... there are times where I have to leave my computer to continue to work with other people or attend meetings or just let it compute some long task.

Comment: Also, being logged on, but surfing on SO would still be regarded as "working"... uhmm...

Comment: @RoyDictus i just want to know how to approach it .@Sayse i know its very harmful tool but have to track the time based on client needs. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you write a windows service, and check for the last input ?

```
// Step 1
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Steps 2 and 3
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern bool 
        GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

//Step 4
internal struct LASTINPUTINFO 
{
    public uint cbSize;

    public uint dwTime;
}
```

The above code is explained well in this codeproject link. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13384/Getting-the-user-idle-time-with-C

Comment: Almost looking for the same ..Thanks a Ton :)